# Subscribe (or list) all of an applications distributed notifications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need a list of all the distributed notifications that iTunes and Spotify publish. I can't seem to find such a thing on SO or Google, so I wanted to see if maybe I could just subscribe to all the notifications and just note down which ones are triggered. I've successfully subscribed to one, but I can't subscribe to all of them.

```
// Works just fine
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(itunesNotification)
               name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" object:nil];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(spotifyNotification)
               name:@"com.spotify.client.PlaybackStateChanged" object:nil];

// Doesn't work :(
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(itunesNotification)
               name:@"com.apple.iTunes" object:nil];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(itunesNotification)
               name:@"com.apple.iTunes.*" object:nil];
// Same result with com.spotify.client and .*
```

Again, if I could have a list of all the iTunes/Spotify notifcations, that would work as well. My intention is not to subscribe to all notifications in the end, but rather to see what's out there and pick a few. Hope that makes sense, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! You can observe all of the distributed notifications on your Mac by supplying `nil` as the name.

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(allNotifications:) name:nil object:nil];
```

Comment: Be careful, this won't give you "all of an applications notifications" but **all** notifications in the `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` system. You'll get (depending on how many applications are running and using it) a **massive amount** of notifications. You might need to filter them in `-allNotifications` using the `userInfo` dict of the notification in an `if` statement

Comment: Not the case anymore since Catalina.